# Computing the Fréchet Derivative of a Function in a Vector Space

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, vector-spaces, operator-theory, frechet-derivative

Let $X$ be the vector space of continuous functions on the interval $[0,\pi]$ equipped with the uniform norm. Let $F: X\rightarrow X$ be a function given by
$$
[F(f)](x) = \sin(f(x)),\quad (f\in X).
$$
And I am trying to compute the Fréchet derivative $F'$. Here is my attempt:

> Take some $f,h\in X$ and try to evaluate the difference $F(f+h) - F(f)$:
>   \begin{align*}
> [F(f+h)-F(f)](x) &= \sin(f(x)+h(x)) - \sin(f(x))\\
> &= \sin(f(x))\cos(h(x)) + \cos(f(x))\sin(h(x)) - \sin(f(x))\\
> &= [\cos(h(x))-1]\sin(f(x)) - \cos(f(x))\sin(h(x))
> \end{align*}

So when $h\rightarrow 0$, the terms $[\cos(h(x))-1]\sin(f(x))$ and $\cos(f(x))\sin(h(x))$ both tend to zero, so I am quite confused about how to choose a valid candidate for the derivative.
Could anyone please give me a hint about how to proceed? Any of your help will be highly appreciated! :)

Comment: It's a good thing both tend to zero, otherwise we would not have a derivative since a derivative is a difference quotient, not a difference. Generally the trick is to use the vector space feature and take the limit as a scalar $\epsilon$ times $h$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Define $L_f: X\to X$ by $L_fh(x)=-h(x)\cos (f(x))$. Then $T$ is a continuous linear map on $X$. Show that $\frac {\|F(f+h)-F(f)-L_fh\|} {\|h\|} \to 0$ as $\|h\|\to 0$ using the following basic facts:   $\frac {\cos a -1}a \to 0$ as $ a \to 0$ and $\frac {\sin a } a -1 \to 0$ as $ a\to 0$. Hence $F'(f)=L_f$.